# QGIS: save DEM from xyz-tiles returns area with unrealistically low raster values

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, export, elevation

Newer QGIS version (I use 3.26.2) come with pre-installed XYZ Tiles connection `Mapzen Global Terrain`: a worldwide digital elevation model. For local use, I donwloaded a section of it (right click layer > export).

The result I get is somehow strange. The raster represents what I expect (a DEM raster), but with some areas completely out of range: see the two black "bars", containing pixel values of -32768 - whereas the input layer has a pixel value range of -11000 to 9000 (min/max for earth's surface). In the mountainous area of interest (swiss Alps), there should be no spot lower than a few hundred meters above sea level.

So the resulting DEM raster should have a min/max range of about (say: 500) to 3970 meters. Still, I have these rectangular shaped areas with raster values of -32768: 33 km deep "canyons" that are not there.

It seems that these represent `NO DATA` values, even if the input layer clearly has data there. When I check the `no data` box in the export dialog, the respective areas are output as `no data` values in these areas (instead of -32768).

Can someone tell what went wrong respectively how to solve the problem?

I tried this with other regions of interest as well with similar results. Not sure if others can reproduce this behaviour.

*The two vertical black "bars" are the problematic areas, the rest is OK:*
[image]

*Result in 3D view with "canyons" (red arrows) and "correct" surface (blue ellipses):*
[image]

Comment: -32768 is almost certainly the NODATA value meaning missing data.

Comment: That's what I suspected, too (nodata) - but the input layer clearly does not show any missing values there.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but try checking the "no data" box and adding -32768 and see what happens? By default, I believe qgis doesn't use the entire raster range, though you can force it do so.

Comment: The respective areas are output as `no data` values in this case (instead of `-32768`)

Comment: 32768 is 2^15, which is the maximum negative value of a 16 bit signed float. I am quite positive (pun intended) that value is to be seen as a NULL / invalid (for some reason I don't know)

Comment: Yes, that's very probably the case. So the question is: what's the reason for that? Can someone reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: If the data is public, could you share a link? You appear to be saying that QGIS sees the value as -32768, but the input file doesn't show it as -32768 at that point? You think QGIS is interpreting data incorrectly? I'm suspicious your export may have changed NODATA values to -32768 or something

Comment: Yes, data is public and can be found in QGIS Browser panel under XYZ Tiles > Mapzen Global Terrain. I double checked by applying the same style to this XYZ-tile layer and the extracted/exported/saved result - no `nodata` values in input, just in the output.